# Insert/update product programmaticaly

Tags: product, import, importexport

My problem:
I insert the product from management software into magento.
The problem is here:

->setStoreId(1)
->setWebsiteIds(array(1))

I have:
1 web site (id:1)
1 store (id:1)
3 view (id 1, 2, 3)

if i use

->setStoreId(1)
->setWebsiteIds(array(1))

I update only the view the view 1 but not upgrade the other view or store.

if i want update or insert product into main web site(global, what should I enter??

Thanks a lot

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$productId = 1;
$storeId  = 1;
$websiteIds = array(1);
$identifierType = null; //
$product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($productId, $storeId, $identifierType);   
if (Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
}else {
    $product->setStoreId($storeId);
    $product->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds);   
}

try {
    $product->save();
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
```